# Windows creates invalid shortcuts

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, shortcuts

I have my OS - windows 8.1 installed on C:, but every application is installed on D:.

When I install application and shortcut is created, shortcut Start in field is set to D:\Programs... and this is the right path, but TARGET field gets set to C:\Program Files(x86)... which is invalid path, because program is not installed there.

Comment: "up vote 0 down vote favorite" copy paste error, isn't it?

Comment: copied it from my question on stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

Shortcuts are not created by Windows, they are created by the installer. Installers are just programs, just like any other program. There are too many installers available on Windows which means they are not always trivial to set up, and sometimes people who write an installer for their software screw up. In your case, someone let you chose the install directory and forgot that maybe the shortcut should point to the actual install directory, instead of default.

The testers were either inexperienced, non-existent, or didn't have enough time to test much beyond the most likely usage scenarios.

I'm pretty sure most other software will do fine.

Comment: well, if skype does this invalid shortcut, i guess its the microsoft's installer's fault

Comment: Microsoft doesn't use "the microsoft installer". Like many other companies they use various different installers. And installers are programs that are configurable. This is just Skype being incompetent.